# Call a method on the parent class of an initialized object

Tags: python

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def intro(self):
        return "I am an animal named %s" %self.name


class Dog(Animal):

    def intro(self):
        return "I am a dog named %s" %self.name 


class Puppy(Dog):

    def intro(self):
        return "I am a puppy named %s" %self.name


dizzy = Puppy("Dizzy")
```

What would I do if I wanted a single instance of dizzy.intro() to return the Dog or the Animal `intro` method?  i.e., I don't want to do a super call within the class to override the method, but I want just a one-off way to specify which of the three `intro` methods I'm using on this specific instance of `dizzy`?

Comment: *I don't want to do a super call within the class*. Why not? And what does *one-off way to specify which of the three .. methods* look like for you, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It was an interview question.  I'm not really sure what a use case would be.  But for this example, I mean if I wanted the `dizzy` object only to return either "I am an animal/dog named Dizzy", is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer is trying to gage your ability to ask for clarifications too? And `super()` can be used *outside* the method too.

Comment: Ah--I see my mistake now.  I just had the syntax of the `super` call messed up.  Would you like to write up an answer for the rep?  Otherwise I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, and all can be used outside the instance.

You could use `super()`; it takes a class and an instance, and will find the next method in the MRO order:

```
super(Puppy, dizzy).intro()  # uses Dog.intro()
super(Dog, dizzy).intro()    # uses Animal.intro()
```

or you could use the unbound method on the class, passing in the instance manually:

```
Dog.intro(dizzy)
Animal.intro(dizzy)
```

This basically hardcodes what method you use, while using `super()` remains dynamic and will adjust when adding in more complex class hierarchies.

Either method works as part of the method, just swap out `dizzy` with `self`. All you need now is a means of choosing what version you call. Perhaps pick a random one:

```
import random

def any_intro(self):
    cls = random.choice(type(self).__mro__[:-1])
    return cls.intro(self)
```

would use the unbound-method option to pick a class, any class, except for `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you should specify which one you wanna use. Pass it as an argument to intro method. You can do something like this for `Puppy` class

```
def intro(self, parent):
    if(parent == 2):
        super(Animal, self).intro()
    elif(parent == 1):
        super(Dog, self).intro()
    else:
        return "I am a puppy named %s" %self.name
```

Also you can directly call the grandfather method:

```
Animal.intro(self)
```